# Sort file by Element value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sorting

I have the following xml file.(sample) .. I need to sort the 'invoice' nodes by the attribute 'InvcDate'.  Is this even possible in Linq?  Any help would be much appreciated.

I have been trying for some time however I don't have much experience with xml and and am a relative newcomer to programming, so I would be very grateful for any help at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Server>
  <Name>AlignServer</Name>
  <Params>
<marketNo>MT</marketNo>
    <dateFrom>2015-01-06</dateFrom>
    <dateTo>2015-01-09</dateTo>
    <Sales>
      <invoices>
        <invoice>
          <header>
            <InvoiceNum>22947</InvoiceNum>
            <InvcDate>2015/01/07-110104</InvcDate>
          </header>
          <item>
            <SKU>6595456987453</SKU>
            <Qty>-1</Qty>
          </item>
        </invoice>
        <invoice>
          <header>
            <InvoiceNum>23056</InvoiceNum>
            <InvcDate>2015/01/08-020627</InvcDate>
          </header>
          <item>
            <SKU>9845256242255</SKU>
            <Qty>-1</Qty>
          </item>
        </invoice>
        <invoice>
          <header>
            <InvoiceNum>22899</InvoiceNum>
            <InvcDate>2015/01/06-094505</InvcDate>
          </header>
          <item>
            <SKU>5454256565452</SKU>
            <Qty>-1</Qty>
          </item>
          <item>
            <SKU>11111165454130</SKU>
            <Qty>4</Qty>
          </item>
        </invoice>
      </invoices>
    </Sales>
  </Params>
</Server>
```

I have tried

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("C:\\xmlsort\\test.xml");
XElement[] sortedTables = root.Elements("invoices").OrderBy(t =>   (Datetime)t.Element("invdate")).ToArray();
root.ReplaceAll(sortedTables);
root.Save("C:\\xmlsort\\test.xml");
```

What I have done so far - with suggestion from @ec8or and seems to work but still open to suggestions:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("C:\\xmlsort\\test.xml");
var invoices = from p in root.Descendants("invoice")
                       orderby DateTime.ParseExact(p.Element("header").Element("InvcDate").Value, "yyyy/MM/dd-hhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
select p;
XElement[] sortedTables = invoices.ToArray();

root.ReplaceAll(sortedTables);
root.Save("C:\\xmlsort\\output.xml");
```

Comment: have you tried anything? - Show us

Comment: XElement root = XElement.Load("C:\\xmlsort\\test.xml");
            XElement[] sortedTables = root.Elements("invoices").OrderBy(t => (datetime)t.Element("invoice/InvcDate")).ToArray();
            root.ReplaceAll(sortedTables);
            root.Save("C:\\xmlsort\\test.xml");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read you XML in a XElement:

```
XElement element = XElement.Load("doc.xml");
```

Query you XML data:

```
var invoices = from p in element.Descendants ("invoice")
               orderby DateTime.ParseExact(p.Element("header").Element("InvcDate").Value, "yyyy/MM/dd-hhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
               select p;
```

Print it to the console:

```
foreach (var invoice in invoices) {
    Console.WriteLine (invoice.ToString ());
}
```

**EDIT**
Answer to your question in comments.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load ("data.xml");
```

Select all  parent node:

```
var baseElement = doc.XPathSelectElement ("/Server/Params/Sales/invoices");
```

sort the inner  nodes:

```
var sortedElements = baseElement.Elements ()
    .OrderBy (e => (DateTime)e.XPathSelectElement("header/InvoiceNum"))
    .ToList ();
```

replace the current content with the sortet content:

```
baseElement.ReplaceAll (sortedElements);
doc.Save ("out.xml");
```

Comment: Why not use `XElement.Load("doc.xml")` instead of `XElement.Parse (File.ReadAllText("doc.xml"))`?

Comment: XElement root = XElement.Load("C:\\xmlsort\\test.xml");
            var invoices = from p in root.Descendants("invoice")
                           orderby DateTime.ParseExact(p.Element("header").Element("InvcDate").Value, "yyyy/MM/dd-hhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                           select p;
            XElement[] sortedTables = invoices.ToArray();

            root.ReplaceAll(sortedTables);
            root.Save("C:\\xmlsort\\output.xml");

Comment: @PetSerAl You are right.

Comment: @MaltaBd Is that you solution or is that a question? If my answer helped you out, please mark it as answer.  :)

Comment: @ec8or  - I just realised something, the code I used removed previous nodes - "<Name>AlignServer</Name>
  <Params>
<marketNo>MT</marketNo>
    <dateFrom>2015-01-06</dateFrom>
    <dateTo>2015-01-09</dateTo>
    <Sales>  - How do I solve this?